# Why there is a drop in the amount of users who download my app

Tags: android, google-play

I published an app on Google play few months ago. In the last month I was starting to get 10 downloads per day on average (still not a lot, but you have to start some where).
Suddenly 5 days ago, the number of downloads dropped to 0-1 downloads per day.

I don't know why did it happened.
I also would like to say, that I have the following rating: 
5 - 16 users. 
2 - 1 user. 
1 - 1 user.

I got the 1 star rating 5 days ago. Is this the reasons for the drop in downloads numbers?
Is it just coincidence?
What can I do, in order to change it?

Thanks

Comment: tell me which is your app or probably a link.. i will try

Comment: I don't understand why this question is off topic. I read the scope of question in the FAQ. What kind of questions can I ask here? "...practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession..."
What kind of questions should I not ask here?
"...However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK..."

I think that my question is unique to the programming profession, and the scope of it is very narrow.

Please reconsider to open it.
Thanks

Comment: @Rakshi Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to promote my app through here.

Also my question wasn't related to my specific app. I just would like to know if there is such a strong link between 1 rate of 1 to the extreme drop in downloads. I know that users are looking on the reputation, I do it all the time, but does it downgrade me so much in the search?

In case that you still want a link to my app, I'll be glad to send it you through your website.

Again thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your rating is what tells your users about your app. If you reflect poorly on a few users, then you will obviously have a lack of downloads.

View you app with a critical eye and find out what are some of the issues with your app and then enhance it and fix those issues. Its a process. Also pay attention to the logs being sent to you by users and what the users are saying about your app. Listen closely to understand the specific problems with the app that users are having and then fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I did all you just wrote, I know that there are problems with my app, as in any other app, but in the end of the day it is fast, not crashing, useful and 16 other people think the same.

And I also realize that the rating reflects what users think about my app. But since the drop is so big, I thought that there it can't just be that user see this one rating and moving forward. I'm sure that the rating affects the search results, but by how much, does only 1 rate can have such an impact?

Thanks

Comment: It is a good answer but the answer didn't helped me, so I didn't marked it as my accepted answer, but for people who don't know this, it might be important.
Thanks